# Drag out multiple files from browser to desktop using event.dataTransfer.setData

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

Refer to this article http://www.thecssninja.com/html5/gmail-dragout.

It's ok if I drag 1 file only by using:

```
$(".dragme").on('dragstart', function (event) {
    event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("DownloadURL", ["application/octet-stream:image_name.jpg:http://full_image_url"]);
}
```

The DownloadURL value seems to be accept an array of strings.

But when I tried to increase the number of URL in this array, It will become unuseable.

So, What is the correct way to do that?

Comment: Do you want each file will have multiple urls to download.ln article it shows 1 url per file to download

Comment: Yes, each file will have own urls to download.
But getting all file download urls can be done easily by jquery.

My question focuses on event.dataTransfer.setData

Answer (score 1):

You can`t use array to DownloadURL.
The second argument should be DOMString

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/setData

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But, If I want to drag and download multiple files, What is the correct way to do that?

Comment: I think you cannot drag out multiple files. :( Maybe you should use zip library to make a combined file.